# Can't start / connect to Oracle Database - Windows 10 / Oracle 18 XE / SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I am trying to install and run this database for a week... ;< 
I previously tried with Oracle 12 c standard edition but it didn't work - I don't know why ;( 
For now I have uninstalled (I believe) the 12 c and installed 18 XE..

On SQL Plus I have: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error service is running when I try to log in as sysdba

All services on services.msc are running:
- OracleOraDB18Home1MTSRecoveryService
- OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener
- OracleRemExecServiceV2
- OracleServiceXE
- OracleVssWriterXE

On command line when I type "lsnrctl status" I have:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-*******)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                23-NOV-2019 10:41:47
Uptime                    0 days 11 hr. 36 min. 34 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\*****\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\*****\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-*******\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-*******)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And on SQL Developer I have one of 2 errors, depending what I write there: 
- Status : Failure - The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
- Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I don't know what I am doing. I just want to install and run this as quickly as possible to practice on sample database for an exam :( This is my PC, no virtual machines or online servers

Please help me investigate the issue - I checked several answers, even on this site, but I can't understand them well, there are a lot more information there than I need....

Comment: Just go download this vbox image and run it...you're good to go then https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message...

> TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

... and your listener status...

> Services Summary...
>   Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
>   Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   The command completed successfully

... say exactly what's wrong. Your TNS Listener does not know of your Oracle DB service.

You may be right that your Windows "Oracle DB" service is running; that does not mean, though, that your Oracle instance is running. First, log on as admin to your Oracle DB from a Windows user that is privileged to log on locally...

```
set ORACLE_SID=fill_in_the_SID_of_your_Oracle_instance_here
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

... and run...

```
alter system set local_listener = <fill_in_your_local_listener_SID_here>
alter system register;
```

That should register your database service to your TNS Listener, provided that you have your local TNS listener configured in your server's `tnsnames.ora`...

```
<fill_in_your_local_listener_SID_here> = (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = 127.0.0.1)(port = 1521))
```

Too complicated, I know. That's why it's better (for new developers w/o Oracle DBA skills) to use precreated VMs images as suggested by @thatjeffsmith's comment above.